# Stop caching in Symfony

Tags: symfony, caching, production

In my/app/cache, every time I edit a twig file I have to delete the 'prod' folder.

Is there a way to turn caching off?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with using dev env?

Comment: This is the desired behaviour for a production environment. You can also run `php bin/console cache:clear`. For dev, you can access app_dev.php instead

Comment: I can't use it.

Comment: Come on, one can't seriously develop without the dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

Although like stated use dev and if you really can't. Twig has a option for it. I have highlighted the line for you.

Quoted from http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/twig.html#cache

> ### cache
>
> **type:** string **default:** '%kernel.cache_dir%/twig'
>
> Before using the Twig templates to render some contents, they are compiled into regular PHP code. Compilation is a costly process, so the result is cached in the directory defined by this configuration option.
>
> **Set this option to null to disable Twig template compilation**. However, this is not recommended; not even in the dev environment, because the auto_reload option ensures that cached templates which have changed get compiled again.

Answer (score 1):

You can also leave in `prod` env, but set `debug:true` and this will force the templates to always recompile.